# Tesseract force space and character replacement

Tags: python, image, text, python-tesseract, file-conversion

I am doing the tesseract conversion on images file. 
Here is the code used to extract text from images :

```
#Extract text from Image 
im = Image.open(r"C:\Users\XXXXX")
text = pytesseract.image_to_string(im, lang = 'eng',config='--psm 1 --oem 3')
print(text)
```

But while doing it I am getting some errors in the output. Some examples are space loss and wrong conversion.

```
 I am -> Iam
 I -> |
```

Could you please advise on how to correct these errors?

[image: Image to convert in text]

Comment: https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/issues/434 Try changing your psm value

Comment: try psm 7 in config. Btw What your image look like? Just look at those config and choose what is best suited.

Comment: @Pygirl thanks for getting back. I have tried to change psm value but it does not change. The letter "I" is always converted with the sign "|". Is there a way to force the replacement of a character?

Comment: can you show your image?

Comment: @Pygirl I have added an extract of the image above

Comment: Without highlighting ` I` give a pic

Comment: Hi @Pygirl thanks for your support l I have updated the picture.

Comment: add oem 2 or 3 then it should work

Comment: There is nothing you can't do. Only you can change the setting of tesseract. I tried different setting. But it gives my Jam instead of I am. What you can do is like you can either train the model or split each words into images and then detect.